# Compare values in DropDown list and select Default value in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

Controller:

model.addAttribute("gps",gps);
model.addAttribute("user", user);

Error:
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "{groups.id==o.id} ? 'selected' : null"

Views

```
<select id="groups">
<option th:each="o : ${gps}" th:value="${o.id}" th:text="${o.name}" th:selected="{groups.id==o.id} ? true : false">
</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `${groups.id==o.id}` instead of `{groups.id==o.id}`